# What is the equivalent of __footer for left sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

I am loading a different image on left sidebar for different pages. But  I can't modify the left sidebar programatically.

This is the code:

```
function load_image(){

   $pagename = basename(get_permalink());
   echo $pagename;

   if($pagename == "name_of_the_page"){
       echo $pagename;
  }
}

add_action("get_sidebar('left')", "load_image");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this :

Assumed that you have a `sidebar-left.php` and you call [get_sidebar( 'left' )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) to get/include it in your template. In this case, you may check the `page` in your `sidebar-left.php` file and do the conditional work depending on the page using something like this

```
if(is_page( 'Contact' )) { // you may use Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug
    // add the image for contact page
}
elseif(is_page( 'about' )) {
    // add the image for about page
}
else {
    // default image
}
```

Check [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page), [is_single](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single), [is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page), [is_home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home), [is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category), [is_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag) and [is_archive](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive), hope this links will be helpful and relevant as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where am I supposed to find or create the sidebar-left.php? I am using a child-theme. Regads!

Comment: I wrote get_sidebar() on the child theme´s function.php file but doesn't work. I did too on some files on the parent theme but nothing. Sorry, I am new on wordpress.. Where am I supposed to call the function get_sidebar('left) ?

Comment: Put the `sidebar-left.php` file in your child theme's directory so it will override the parent `sidebar-left.php`, `get_sidebar( 'left' )` should be in your template, not in the `functions.php`, read more about [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files).

Comment: Thank you for your help RVC. I've called the sidebar('left); method from functions.php. Regards!

Comment: Well the problem I am having is that the text that is supposed to appear on sidebar is appearing above the header..

Comment: Because you have called the the `get_sidebar` in your `functions.php`, it should be in your template.

Comment: Which file is the template?

Comment: Basically the `index.php` in the root of your parent template, there you may find an `index.php` file and it may contains the functions such as `get_header()`, 'get_sidebar('left')', so if you have a file in your parent template with name `sidebar-left.php` then you have to put a file using same name in your child theme and in the `index.php` file `get_sidebar('left')` call will use the child `sidebar-left.php` instead of one that is in you parent theme.

Comment: Read this article about [child theme](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/child-themes-basics-and-creating-child-themes-in-wordpress/).